# Sorting a large list of rss feed items by publish_parsed or updated_parsed

Tags: python, feedparser

I have a large list of rss feed items that I'm attempting to sort by key 'published_parsed' like so:

```
allheadlines.sort(key=lambda hl:hl[0]['published_parsed'], reverse=True)
```

The problem is this is returning a key error as some feed items do not have the key published_parsed. I tried changing to updated_parsed but again, some feed items do not have the key updated_parsed. After interchanging the two in the solution given below:

```
allheadlines.sort(key=lambda hl:hl[0].get('published_parsed', hl[0].get('updated_parsed')), reverse=True)
```

I have another problem. There is an rss feed that's not returning one or both of these keys. How would I sort everything that do have at least 1 of these keys and do nothing for the items that do not have either of these keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `dict.get`

**Ex:**

```
allheadlines.sort(key=lambda hl:hl[0].get('published_parsed', hl[0].get('updated_parsed')), reverse=True)
```

Comment: I received a TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'time.struct_time'

Comment: You do have `published_parsed` or `updated_parsed` key in your dict correct?

Comment: I guess I have another problem that I just discovered after using your solution. These keys should be in the dict, however, the rss feed might not be returning one or both of these keys